# How to reduce vertical space on some certain chapters on the ToC (Not All Chapters)

Tags: table-of-contents, book-class

I'm afraid if i show my MWE you might misunderstand what i mean cz my code is really really bad and has many hacks. So in this case, forgive me not to include my MWE.

So, let's say i have 6 chapters. I'm using `chapter*{...}` command. And i want chapter 1-3 have 1cm vertical space.

- Chapter 1: Abstract
- Chapter 2: Acknowledgement
- Chapter 3: Preface

And Chapter 4-6 have 2cm vertical space.

- Chapter 4: Chapter 1
- Chapter 5: Chapter 2
- Chapter 6: Chapter 3

The result must be like [this](https://ibb.co/Cmyv7vG)

Can you help me please? Help is really appreciated.

Comment: That is not line spacing (line spacing means something else for us). If, say, chapter four has a very long title that spans more than one line. Then those like will not have twoline spacing. You're looking for the default spacing that is inserted above each chapter entry.

Comment: @daleif oh sorry. I just don't know what the name is. Please see my edit. Thanks.